Acumatica issue with looking up BillCustomerID and BillLocationID from Customer
I am trying to look up and display the email on the ServiceOrderEntry screen from a parent customer location defined by the Customer record in the BillCustomerID and BillLocationID fields.
protected void FSServiceOrder_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)

{
      
var row = (FSServiceOrder)e.Row;

CustomerMaint graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<CustomerMaint>();
graph.BAccount.Current = PXSelect<Customer, Where<Customer.bAccountID,Equal<Required<FSServiceOrder.customerID>>>>.Select(Base, row.CustomerID);

CustomerLocationMaint parentLocationGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<CustomerLocationMaint>();

parentLocationGraph.Location.Current = PXSelect<Location, Where<Location.bAccountID, Equal<Required<Customer.billCustomerID>>,And<Location.locationID, Equal<Required<Customer.billLocationID>>>>>.Select(Base,graph.CurrentCustomer.Current.BillCustomerID, graph.CurrentCustomer.Current.BillLocationID);

}

When I try to publish, I get the following error:

[2024-05-29 01:01:21.813] \App_RuntimeCode\ServiceOrderEntry.cs(118): error CS0426: The type name 'billCustomerID' does not exist in the type 'Customer'
[2024-05-29 01:01:21.813] \App_RuntimeCode\ServiceOrderEntry.cs(119): error CS0426: The type name 'billLocationID' does not exist in the type 'Customer'
[2024-05-29 01:01:21.813] \App_RuntimeCode\ServiceOrderEntry.cs(119): error CS1061: 'Customer' does not contain a definition for 'BillCustomerID' and no accessible extension method 'BillCustomerID' accepting a first argument of type 'Customer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
[2024-05-29 01:01:21.813] \App_RuntimeCode\ServiceOrderEntry.cs(119): error CS1061: 'Customer' does not contain a definition for 'BillLocationID' and no accessible extension method 'BillLocationID' accepting a first argument of type 'Customer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
[2024-05-29 01:01:21.813] \App_RuntimeCode\ServiceOrderEntry.cs(118): error CS0426: The type name 'billCustomerID' does not exist in the type 'Customer'

I have looked at the Customer in the DAC and I can see the BillLocationID and the BillCustomerID fields defined there.  They are defined in the CurrentCustomer view under CustomerMaint.
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

You are don't need to reference the Customer DAC in a PXSelect Required clause.  Try the following
 PXSelect<Location, Where<Location.bAccountID, Equal<Required<Location.bAccountID>>,And<Location.locationID, Equal<Required<Location.locationID>>>>>.Select(Base,graph.CurrentCustomer.Current.BillCustomerID, graph.CurrentCustomer.Current.BillLocationID);


Customer table contains billLocationID field but Customer DAC doesn't.
The billLocationID field is declared in FSxCustomer DAC extension.
Try referencing FSxCustomer DAC instead of Customer DAC:
PXSelect<Customer, 
Where<FSxCustomer.billLocationID, Equal<Required<FSxCustomer.billLocationID>>>>...

